Asymptotic distribution of MLE of $\sigma$ for $N(0,\sigma^2)$
I know that given $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, the MLE for $\sigma$ is $\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2}$.  I want to find the asymptotic distribution for $\hat{\sigma}$. If I can find the asymptotic distribution $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ then I could probably use the delta method to get what I am looking for. The problem is that I don't see how to apply the CLT to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ . Any suggestions?

Why are you messing with the sample mean $\bar{X}$ when you know the mean is zero?

Your choice of MLE suggests you didn't actually write the likelihood for the specific model in question, which is
$$\mathcal L (\sigma \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto \sigma^{-n} \exp \left( -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{2\sigma^2} \right),$$
hence the log-likelihood is
$$\ell (\sigma \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto -n \log \sigma - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$  Maximizing $\ell$ for a fixed sample yields a different MLE than what you wrote.
That said, you should know that $(X_i/\sigma)^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$, so $$\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \sim \chi^2(n).$$  This is the key result you need to compute the distribution of $\hat \sigma$.

+1 explained well.
